# ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean in tomcat

Tags: java, spring, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I am trying to use ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean in tomcat, does this bean interfere with tomcat threads?

```
<bean id="executorService" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="40" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="40" />
    <property name="allowCoreThreadTimeOut" value="true" />
    <property name="keepAliveSeconds" value="5" />
</bean>
```

Comment: @ Sotirios Delimanolis - in regards to limiting the number of catalina threads or jndi connection pool threads.. etc

Comment: I still don't understand what you concern is. That bean will end up creating 40 threads that are completely unrelated to any other thread(s).

Comment: We have started to see a weird issue in production where jdbc connection pool is running out of the connections after this change..i am not exactly sure if this is causing it though..want to be sure this is somehow not causing it...

Comment: Note that connections are completely unrelated to threads as well. They are objects in their own right. They won't just disappear. With more threads (from this bean), you might have more thread context switching within the process. That's all.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification..if you can answer that to it I will mark it off.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javadoc of `ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean` states

> JavaBean that allows for configuring a
>   `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor` in bean style [...]

In other words, once Spring processes the bean definition, it will create a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with the properties you provided. This object will create a standalone pool of threads. These threads are unrelated to any other threads in your application.

They will interfere with other threads in the sense that the thread scheduler will have more threads to share time slices with. That's it.

> We have started to see a weird issue in production where jdbc
>   connection pool is running out of the connections after this change..i
>   am not exactly sure if this is causing it though..want to be sure this
>   is somehow not causing it...

Unless you are doing somehow sharing the connections between these threads and others, I can't imagine that thread pool causing the behavior you describe.